# Transparent wrapper class for data structure in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented

I needed a `deque` who's `maxlen` can be set again after it has been initialized. So, since new-style classes in Python are treated as types, I decided to create a new class borrowing from `deque` to accomplish this. My approach is to have an internal `deque` as an attribute and when `maxlen` is set, it replaces the internal `deque` with a new one, initialized to the old contents and the new `maxlen`.

I tried subclassing `deque` but it's too crude, creating a `deque` that's useless on top with the useful one internally. So I chose to simply have all of the wrapper class's attributes (except special ones) point to the internal `deque`'s. However, due to how new-style classes work, the special  attributes have to be handled manually. Since all I want is to override `maxlen`'s setter, all of this seems inelegant and I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way of accomplishing this.

From what I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11635543/2838033), it seems I could subclass this class in `__new__` to skip overriding the special attributes, but that seems even more hairy than what I already wrote.

This is the result, stripped of extraneous comments (complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/MechaLynx/8273e26288f2ed7de78604f7fbce35a1) if you want something runnable, with tests):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function

from collections import deque


class ResizableDeque(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.internal = deque(*args, **kwargs)

        skip_list = [
            'maxlen'
        ] + [attr for attr in dir(deque) if attr.startswith('__') and
             attr.endswith('__')]

        for attr in dir(deque):
            if attr not in skip_list:
                setattr(self, attr, getattr(self.internal, attr))

    @property
    def maxlen(self):
        return self.internal.maxlen

    @maxlen.setter
    def maxlen(self, value):
        templist = list(self.internal)
        self.internal = deque(templist, value)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.internal.__str__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.internal.__repr__()

    def __getitem__(self, value):
        return self.internal.__getitem__(value)

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        return self.internal.__setitem__(index, value)

    # these have not been tested
    def __copy__(self):
        return self.internal.__copy__()

    def __delitem__(self, index):
        return self.internal.__delitem__(index)

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        return self.internal.__iadd__(other)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.internal.__len__()

    # not sure if overriding __sizeof__ is wise this way
    def __sizeof__(self):
        return self.__sizeof__() + self.internal.__sizeof__()

    # pretty sure this is ok
    def __format__(self, spec):
        return self.internal.__format__(spec)
```

Comment: I think this question better fits stackoverflow

Comment: @warvariuc the code works, I'm just looking for comments on whether this is the proper way of doing what I did.

Comment: Whatever. Try using `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` magic methods to catch access to attributes and forward it to the wrapped object.

Comment: As a comment, as no time for a full review: I see that in `__init__` stuff gets copied from `.internal`, but not updated when `internal` changes on setting `maxlen`.

Answer (score 1):

## Correctness?

I copied your code, and added the following testcase.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    k = ResizableDeque(maxlen=10)
    k.append(12)
    print(k)
    k.maxlen = 10
    k.append(13)
    k += [14]
    print(k)
```

Expected result:

```
deque([12], maxlen=10)
deque([12, 13, 14], maxlen=10)
```

But I got

```
deque([12], maxlen=10)
deque([12, 14], maxlen=10)
```

The reason is that you copy over a bunch of items in `__init__`, but not in the `maxlen.setter`.

## Whitelisting vs blacklisting

In `__init__` you copy several items over using a `skip_list`. Why not explicitly define the items you *want* to copy over instead?

Actually, why copy at all? Performance would be a proper reason, but then I'd suggest copying just the items that have proven to be necessary to copy (after profiling).

Comment: Excellent catch, I can't believe I missed something like this. I use a skip list instead of an inclusion list because if the implementation of `deque` changes (unlikely) I want the default behavior to be to alias every non-special attribute. This is because I want `ResizableDeque` to be like `deque` in every respect except how `maxlen` works. Having an inclusion list makes it more likely that I'll need to make changes.

Comment: Also, I don't intend to copy anything - from what I tested in the interpreter, that `setattr()` line makes all of `ResizableDeque`'s attributes point to `internal`'s. On the gist, I've got some lines commented out that test exactly this and the attributes test as being the same. If profiling shows this to be too intensive I might change it, but this is more about making usage of the class easy - performance of this operation shouldn't be critical for the use I intend it for.

Comment: I _am_ looking into @warvariac's suggestion of using `__getattr__`, though that looks to me like it improves performance during instance creation but sacrifices it on lookups and conditionals during use.